# I got this two errors while vagrant up on islandora-playbook repository, do you have any idea about the problem?

Tags: vagrant, islandora

fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'motomo_sql_dump_create | changed' failed. The error was: No filter named 'changed' found.\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/oem/islandora-playbook/roles/external/Islandora-Devops.matomo/tasks/console_install.yml': line 12, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name:\n  ^ here\n"}

fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "Could not find or access 'Ubuntu-20.yml'\nSearched in:\n\t/home/oem/islandora-playbook/roles/external/geerlingguy.java/vars/Ubuntu-20.yml\n\t/home/oem/islandora-playbook/roles/external/geerlingguy.java/Ubuntu-20.yml\n\t/home/oem/islandora-playbook/roles/external/geerlingguy.java/tasks/vars/Ubuntu-20.yml\n\t/home/oem/islandora-playbook/roles/external/geerlingguy.java/tasks/Ubuntu-20.yml\n\t/home/oem/islandora-playbook/vars/Ubuntu-20.yml\n\t/home/oem/islandora-playbook/Ubuntu-20.yml on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}

Answer (score 1):

The 1st error relates to changes in Ansible. In your Ansible playbook (...`console_install.yml`) change `motomo_sql_dump_create | changed` to `motomo_sql_dump_create is changed`. I don't know about the 2nd error

Answer (score 0):

Probably the wrong place to ask an Islandora question. The Slack channel is the fastest. Ideally I'd suggest to switch to the ISLE (dockerized) version instead of the Ansible version. I know that's not always possible, so this looks like a previously common issue to run into. If I remember correctly it's a Ansible Version issue. The Ansible deployment of Islandora was locked into a very specific version due in part to a lack of interest in that type of build process.